# Reflect data change in realtime using Kotlin & Livedata is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I am implementing a solution wherein a sees a list of contacts along with the current priority - High, Medium and Low. The user can then change the status through the priority by using a dialog box and the room DB is updated but the UI does not get updated as expected. It is only when I recreate the activity does the change appear. I am not using a ViewModel.

What do I need to change in the below code for the same to happen?`

```
class CrmContacts : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressDialog
var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null //the used id of the user using the app
var managecontactsadapter: ManageContactsAdapter? = null
var reference: DatabaseReference? = null
var rvCRM: RecyclerView? = null
private val _contsCRMLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Contact>>()
private val crmContactsLiveData: LiveData<ArrayList<Contact>> = _contsCRMLiveData

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crm_contacts, container, false)

    val srchView: SearchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_user_contacts)

    //Search
    val searchPlateId: Int = srchView.context.resources
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null)
    val searchPlate: View =
        srchView.findViewById(searchPlateId)
    searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    val linearLayout1 = srchView.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
    val linearLayout2 = linearLayout1.getChildAt(2) as LinearLayout
    val linearLayout3 = linearLayout2.getChildAt(1) as LinearLayout
    val autoComplete = linearLayout3.getChildAt(0) as AutoCompleteTextView
    autoComplete.textSize = 14f

    srchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
    srchView.isFocusable = false

    //Progress Bar
    progressBar = ProgressDialog(activity)
    progressBar.setCancelable(false)
    progressBar.setMessage("Loading...")


    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    rvCRM = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCRM)
    rvCRM!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rvCRM!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    displayContacts()
    crmContactsLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        rvCRM!!.adapter = managecontactsadapter
    })

    contact_fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, EditContact::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Edit", false)
        this.startActivity(intent)
    }

    crmFilter.setOnClickListener {
        val options = arrayOf<CharSequence>(
            "Lead",
            "Qualified",
            "Proposal",
            "Client",
            "Invoiced",
            "Unpaid",
            "Clear Filter"
        )
        var salesTag = ""
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        builder.setTitle("Filter by?")
        builder.setItems(options, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, which ->
            if (which == 0) {
                salesTag = "High"
                filtercontactby(salesTag)
            }
            if (which == 1) {
                salesTag = "Medium"
                filtercontactby(salesTag)
            }
            if (which == 2) {
                salesTag = "Low"
                filtercontactby(salesTag)
            }
        })
        builder.show()
    }

}

private fun filtercontactby(salesTag: String) {

    val mupdateList = ArrayList<Contact>()
    val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())
    val contact = db.contactsDao().getFilterContacts(salesTag)
    if(contact.isEmpty())
    {
        val nocontacts = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noContacts)
        nocontacts!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val notice = "uh oh! No Contacts have been tagged as " + "$salesTag!"
        nocontacts.text = notice
    }
    mupdateList.clear()
    for (i in contact) {
        mupdateList.add(i)
    }

    managecontactsadapter = ManageContactsAdapter(requireContext(), mupdateList)
    rvCRM!!.adapter = managecontactsadapter

}

private fun displayContacts() {

    val mupdateList = ArrayList<Contact>()
    val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())
    val contact = db.contactsDao().getContacts()
    val nocontacts = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noContacts)
    if(contact.isEmpty())
    {
        nocontacts!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        nocontacts.text = "uh oh! Please use the add clients/contacts button below!"
    } else {
        nocontacts!!.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    for (i in contact) {
        mupdateList.add(i)
    }
    managecontactsadapter = ManageContactsAdapter(requireContext(), mupdateList)
    rvCRM!!.adapter = managecontactsadapter
}

private fun searchForContacts(searchString: String) {

    val mupdateList = ArrayList<Contact>()
    val nocontacts = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noContacts)
    val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())
    val contact = db.contactsDao().getBySearch(searchString)
    if(contact.isEmpty())
    {
        nocontacts!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        nocontacts.text = "uh oh! Search is empty, try again?!"
    } else {
        nocontacts!!.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    mupdateList.clear()
    for (i in contact) {
        mupdateList.add(i)
    }

    managecontactsadapter = ManageContactsAdapter(requireContext(), mupdateList)
    rvCRM!!.adapter = managecontactsadapter
}

//Search Contacts using SearchView
override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
    managecontactsadapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    if (query != null) {
        searchForContacts("%${query}%")
    }
    return true
}

override fun onQueryTextChange(keyWord: String?): Boolean {

    if (keyWord != null) {
        searchForContacts("%${keyWord}%")
    }
    return true
}
```

}

RoomDAO returns a List of object - LiveData

Adapter Class code:

```
class ManageContactsAdapter(
mContext: Context,
mupdateList: ArrayList<Contact>
) : 

RecyclerView.Adapter<ManageContactsAdapter.MyViewHolder?>() {
    private val layoutInflater = mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    private val mContext: Context
    private val mupdateList: List<Contact>

    init {
        this.mContext = mContext
        this.mupdateList = mupdateList
    }
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var contLabel: TextView? = null
    var ContactName: TextView? = null
    var ContactDetails: LinearLayout? = null
    private var ContactProfileImage: ShapeableImageView
    private var contFavEdit: ImageButton
    private lateinit var salesLabel: CardView

    init {
        contLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contLabel)
        ContactProfileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ContactProfileImage)
        ContactName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ContactName)
        ContactDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ContactDetails)
        contFavEdit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contFavEdit)
        salesLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.salesLabel)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_row, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mupdateList.size
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val contact = mupdateList[position]

    with(holder.itemView) {
        ContactName.text = contact.name
        if(contact.label != null){
            contLabel.text = contact.label
            if (contact.label == "High" || contact.label == "high"){
                contLabel.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.ColorPurple))
            } else if (contact.label == "Medium"){
                contLabel.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.ColorBlueNote))
            } else if (contact.label == "Low"){
                contLabel.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.ColorMaroon))
            } 
        }

        if(contact.favorite == true){
            holder.itemView.contFavEdit.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favsel)
        } else {
            holder.itemView.contFavEdit.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav)
        }

        Picasso.get().load(contact.photoUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_whatshot_24).fit().centerCrop().into(
                ContactProfileImage
            )
        ContactDetails.removeAllViews()
        contact.numbers.forEach {
            val detail = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.row_contact_data,
                ContactDetails,
                false
            )
            detail.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_local_phone_black_24dp)
            detail.ContactData.text = it
            ContactDetails.addView(detail)
        }
        contact.emails.forEach {
            val detail = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.row_contact_data,
                ContactDetails,
                false
            )
            detail.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mail_black_24dp)
            detail.ContactData.text = it
            ContactDetails.addView(detail)
        }
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(mContext, ContactDetailsHome::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("contact", contact as Serializable)
        intent.putExtra("Edit", true)
        mContext.startActivity(intent)
    }

    holder.itemView.contFavEdit.setOnClickListener {
       if(contact.favorite == true){
           contact.favorite = false
           holder.itemView.contFavEdit.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav)
           updatefav(contact,false)
       } else {
           contact.favorite = true
           holder.itemView.contFavEdit.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favsel)
           updatefav(contact,true)
       }
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {

        val options = arrayOf<CharSequence>(
            "High",
            "Medium",
            "Low",
        )
        var salesTag = ""
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
        builder.setTitle("Contact is a?")
        builder.setItems(options, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, which ->
            if (which == 0) {
                salesTag = "High"
                updateDB(contact, salesTag)
            }
            if (which == 1) {
                salesTag = "Medium"
                updateDB(contact, salesTag)
            }
            if (which == 2) {
                salesTag = "Low"
                updateDB(contact, salesTag)
            }
        })
        builder.show()
        true
    }

}

private fun updateDB(contactL: Contact, salesTag: String) {
    val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(mContext)
    val ev = Contact(
        contactL.id,
        contactL.name,
        contactL.lookupKey,
        contactL.photoUri,
        salesTag,
        null,
        contactL.favorite
    )
    db.contactsDao().updateContact(ev)
}

private fun updatefav(contactL: Contact, fav: Boolean) {
    val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(mContext)
    db.contactsDao().updatefav(contactL.id, fav)
}

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

}

Comment: Can you paste the code of your adapter class?

Comment: Hi che10, have added the code for the same...

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine as such, I feel your adapter is not being updated, instead of reassigning the adapter everytime what you can do is, add a function inside your adapter class to update the list data and refresh as follows.

```kotlin
private fun updateContacts(contactList: ArrayList<Contact>){
        this.mupdateList.clear()
        this.mupdateList.addAll(contactList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

And then wherever you are updating your list, like in the `filtercontactby()` function, you can simply go like

```kotlin
managecontactsadapter?.updateContacts(mupdateList)
```

Comment: but to call the updateContacts function would mean I would need to read the DB again in the adapter...? How else would I regenerate the contacts list? Also notifydatset  changed does not work too...

Comment: @madhall No you are understanding it wrong, when some user selects a filter, you make a call like this`filtercontactby(salesTag)`, what you need to do is add the `updateContacts` function in your Adapter and inside the `filtercontactby()` function use the `managecontactsadapter?.updateContacts(mupdateList)`.

You don't actually need to create an Adapter everytime, just create one at top as you have already done and use it.

Comment: yes, that would be a solution but my filter is working well. The issue is when I am changing the status from High to Medium using an AlertDialog set on the item - this code is present in the adapter and updates the DB but unable to refresh there...

Comment: @madhall The code is very messy right now, I would suggest you to separate and keep your business logic to the activity itself even if you do not want to use `ViewModel`. Your adapter should technically only just show the data supplied to it and doesn't need other things.

So what you can do is as you change the status, hit your query in the activity, fetch the result and pass it onto the Adapter by creating a method for the same as I have in the answer.

Comment: sounds good now to figure out how to call a fragment function from the adapter! whew

Comment: @madhall Why do you need that? Also you can use an interface for that, implement the interface in fragment and then you can have a sort of callback

Answer (score 0):

notifyDatasetChange() is no longer recommended and does not work in most cases as of June 2021. The way I solved this is by using the additional notifyfeatures provided. In my case only an item was being updated so I had to apply

notifyItemChanged(position)

This updated the relevant item in the recyclerview only! So if your notifyDatasetChange() is not working in the adapter - it is because you might have to apply Item specific notification.